# Batch script that removes a column from .csv file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I have a .csv file with over 20 columns and i'm looking to remove the 5th one, and save the result.

Using ';' as delimiter.

Here is what I belive to be the closest I got to the expected result, I looked on many other similar threads but did not manage to get any to work.

```
    @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (input.csv) DO (
  SET "line=%%a"
  SET "line=!line:;= ; !"
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=;" %%p IN ("!line!") DO (
   SET "line=%%p;%%r"
   SET "line=!line: ; =;!"
   ECHO(!line!
  )
 )
)>output.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

I have also tried this to see if it works, not with all lines but output file is empty

```
@echo off>output.csv
cls
setlocal 

for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=," %%1 in (input.csv) do (
    echo %%1,%%2,%%3,%%5>>fourcol.csv
)
type output.csv
```

Here is the header with the first lines of the input file type.

```
CA      CB          Libelle   PV HT     Qt Stock    Family  ...
AR00145 242719258   EFIP7P       5          (blank) (blank) ...
AR00176 764776562   MI7ROSE      3          (blank) (blank) ...
AR00261 3.70072E+12 EA52016      3          (blank) (blank) ...
```

the separator is ;  and what is blank must remain blank.
The sample above is from Excel to try and make it more comprehensive, the actual form when opening with notepad is

```
CA;CB;...
AR00145;242719258;...
```

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534752/deleting-replacing-characters-delimited-by-commas/46536396#46536396

Comment: `(for /F "tokens=1-5* delims=;" %%a in (input.csv) do echo %%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%f) > output.csv`

Comment: @Aacini Output is blank :-(

Comment: Please, post a few lines of your input.csv file, so we both could do a test with the same data... **Edit** your question! Don't post data here, in comments...

Comment: @Aacini I have added the header with some lines of my csv file in the main post, thanks!

Comment: In your question you said: **"Using ';' as delimiter"**. I assumed that _the columns_ are delimited by a semicolon, but your data example have not a single `';'`!

Comment: @Aacini the columns are delimited by a ';' but I opened the file and copy&pasted from excel to try and make it more comprehensive, in when opening with notepad or anything else instead of the space between columns there are ';' 's

Comment: Please reread my first comment, where I said: "Please, post a few lines of your input.csv file, **so we both could do a test with the same data**". If you don't understand this point, then I can't help you. Sorry... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini I've added some more explanations and a screenshot with the same file open in both excel and notepad, I'm sorry for not being able to explain properly.

Comment: This is easier in PowerShell, which has native CSV processing baked right in.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart There's no way of doing this on native Windows without anything else? I'm adding this to a list of programs that I made to automate some tasks for workmates that are not very computer oriented.

Comment: PowerShell is native on Windows starting in Windows 7. No additional install needed.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Oh snap, never used it, I'm having a look right now, is there any way to make something like a shortcut or .exe from it so it is more user friendly for other people?

Comment: I would suggest to get your needed script to work first, and then worry later about how to tell people to run it.

Comment: We not need a "more comprehensive" view of the data, nor more explanations or a screenshot of how the file appears _in your computer_. What we need is a way to **create the input.csv file** in our computers using the data that appear in this page _only_. I invite you to try to do the same (create an input.csv file with _the same contents_ than the yours) and then explain how we can do that...

Comment: @Aacini To create the input.csv file all you need is random words separated by ';' and the first line will be the header, just like any other office files, lines (/rows) are separated by a '\n', so i will basically try to delete everything between the fourth and fifth ';' on each line, no matter what is in between them.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is in the Batch file that is shown below. I run the Batch file and type both the input and output files as an example that the program is working correctly, and take a screenshot of the screen to try and make it more comprehensive.

[image]